# Storage Transfer Service To backup Google Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, mobile, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, google-cloud-data-transfer

I have a mobile application that stores data in Google firebase database and firebase Storage service. To prevent data loss, I would like to backup the data stored on both services. Google recently launched Autobackups for database but there is no support for firebase Storage Service. Surfing the net found out that google has a service "Storage Transfer Service". So can I use it to backup my data from google firebase storage bucket?

Comment: Storage Transfer Service is use to transfer from one bucket to another bucket

Comment: I understand but can I use it for backing up the files somehow ? Also, if not then how do I backup google storage bucket

Comment: Usually we backup something to storage bucket not vise versa, You can use multi-regional level bucket (kind of backup in different data center)

Answer (score 0):

Since Firebase Database and Firebase Storage are using the Google Cloud Storage buckets,  I think this is possible by setting up a daily recurring transfer job if you still want to pursue Storage Transfer Service [1]. The exact step is indicated in step #6

> 6. Under Configure transfer, schedule your transfer job to Run now (one time) or Run daily at a time in your local timezone.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#configure